# WebApiConfig.Register() vs. GlobalConfiguration.Configure()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a project with a reference to Web API 2, and I'm working through some issues with routing.  As far as I know, the correct way to approach this is to ensure that the following line of code is present in the `Global.asax` file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

But along the way, I picked up the following code:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

`Global.asax` recognizes both lines of code as valid.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

> ## Migrating From Web API 1
>
> Prior to Web API 2, the Web API project templates generated code like
>   this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // WARNING - Not compatible with attribute routing.
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

> If attribute routing is enabled, this code will throw an exception. If
>   you upgrade an existing Web API project to use attribute routing, make
>   sure to update this configuration code to the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Pass a delegate to the Configure method.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm surprised that Web API 2 still accepts `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` without throwing an error.